# Slow W-Lan with 802.11n - Accesspoint Tp-Link WR1043ND + MacBook + iMac

Tags: wlan

i've got an access point WR1043ND from tp-link.
I joined the wlan with two Macs (MacBook+iMac).
The AP is configured als 802.11bgn mixed mode with encryption wpa/wpa2 automated. 
(Tests without encryption and 802.11n only produce the same result).

The AP has the latest fw update and I tried the alternative fw dd-wrt (same results).

**I got a maximal speed of 1,5mb/s.** The Macs operate in 802.11n (alt-click to the wlan icon).
The connection is very good.

[image]

Comment: Is that 1.5 mega **bits** per second or 1.5 mega **bytes** per second? Also, do you know if that `Senderate: 11` means the WiFi is link is 11Mbps? Lastly, how are you measuring the speed? Is it between two wireless nodes? Between a wireless node and a wired node? Between a wireless node and the Internet? (The speed of both ends affects what you measure! Only wireless to a local wired nodes measures the speed of the WiFi.)

Comment: mb/s= Megabytes per second. mbit/s = Megabits per second. I send a large file from one to the other. I never said something about my internet connection :-) I don't find any documentation for 'Senderate'.

Comment: 1.5MB/s = 12Mbps. The data has to be sent twice (once to the AP, once from the AP), so that's about 24Mbps effective WiFi speed. If you have one 54Mbps device, that's about right.

Comment: @troll actually MB is megabyte, Mb is megabit, and mb is millibit. You should make sure that you use the right one side they are all very very different.

Comment: ok, i'am sorry. Could someone please change this in my post? I can't post pictures with <10 rep

Comment: OK the question is then: why do I only get 11 Mbps? It's an 300+ AP and the macs should bring more than 11 Mbps.

Comment: A second pc with a 300 Mbps Stick just gets 54 Mpbs. The ap is set to 300 -.-

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing this? If your connection to the Internet is 1.5Mb/s down, you could have a 40Gb infrastructure internally and still only get 1.5Mb/s from outside sources.

I bet if you transfer a file between the iMac and MacBook you'll get faster speeds, but your connection to the outside is limited by your ISP.

Comment: I send a large file from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with dd-wrt. The wireless is slow but the wired connection works perfect. This has been a known issue for years. Some wireless chips just don't perform well under dd-wrt.

2 option:

- Reset the stock firmware
- Attach a dedicated AP (hardware).

Comment: I reseted to stock fw and still have these issues